# Re-install Alsa on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I made the mistake to uninstall PulseAudio because i get same [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400950/how-can-i-solve-a-conflict-between-openframeworks-and-other-audio-applications) error between  my OF's app and other audio apps.
It seems a very bad idea and i get this error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
RtApiAlsa::getDeviceInfo:snd_pcm_open error for device (default). No such file or directory
```

i re-install pulseaudio (v4), install QasMixer..and finally tryed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1537375) solution,but nothing changed :(

SOS !..

some checks:

```
aplay -l 
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel HDMI], périphérique 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel HDMI], périphérique 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel HDMI], périphérique 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: HDMI [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```